# Running Hazelcast client in a tomcat container

Tags: mongodb, tomcat, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a web application running in a tomcat container. I'd like to implement a distributed caching solution for the web app using hazelcast. I have a member which is running in local. How do I configure the client to run from inside the tomcat container and connect to the member running in local. Do I need to make any additional configurational changes for connecting to the MongoDB database.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I have a member which is running in local"? How is that deployed and where is it, relatively to your tomcat application?

Comment: in a client-server topology the server is what I am calling member. The member is running as a java application in my local machine. Once I get that up. I start the tomcat server and open my web app on chrome. The client side code should be running along with the web app on the tomcat server in order for me to use the imap in the webapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your Hazelcast client to connect to your local cluster.
You can find documentation about Hazelcast clients [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.10/manual/html/index.html#disk-usage-config). 
And [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.1/manual/html-single/index.html#client-network) is how to configure client network.

Comment: adding hazelcast jars in web-inf/lib folders was the step that I was missing